# How does Face Characterized in .ply File System?

Tags: 3d, ply-file-format

```
ply
        format ascii 1.0           { ascii/binary, format version number }
        comment made by anonymous  { comments are keyword specified }
        comment this file is a cube
        element vertex 8           { define "vertex" element, 8 in file }
        property float32 x         { vertex contains float "x" coordinate }
        property float32 y         { y coordinate is also a vertex property }
        property float32 z         { z coordinate, too }
        element face 6             { there are 6 "face" elements in the file }
        property list uint8 int32 vertex_index
                                   { "vertex_indices" is a list of ints }
        end_header                 { delimits the end of the header }
        0 0 0                      { start of vertex list }
        0 0 1
        0 1 1
        0 1 0
        1 0 0
        1 0 1
        1 1 1
        1 1 0
        4 0 1 2 3                  { start of face list }
        4 7 6 5 4
        4 0 4 5 1
        4 1 5 6 2
        4 2 6 7 3
        4 3 7 4 0
```

Here's a sample ply file format.

According to the comment, it says it represents a `cube`. However, the faces are notated by 5 vertices with its indices. As far as I know, the face of cube charcterized by 4 vertices not by 5.

Where am I misled? Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

In short, the first number in face list tells you **the number of vertices in this list**.

> There is a special form of property definitions that uses the list data type:
>
> **property list**
>
> An example of this is from the cube file above:
>
> *property list uchar int vertex_index*
>
> ***This means that the property "vertex_index" contains first an unsigned char telling how many indices the property contains, followed by a list containing that many integers. Each integer in this variable-length list is an index to a vertex***.

You can read this [Polygon file format introduction](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/ply/) for more information.